# Не подтягивается таблица стилей phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Установил **PhpMyAdmin** на **Ubuntu 18.04**. Устанавливал согласно [инструкции](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#installing-from-git), т.е. склонировал, обновил через `composer`. Всё отлично открылось. Но такое я вижу впервые:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не подтянулись стили? Как это исправить?

> UPD 1 По указанным url нет файлов стилей. На гите тоже нет `css` файлов. Они как-то генерируются на лету? И скачал тему `fallen` **PMA** её тоже не видит, хотя архив распаковал в папку `themes`.

---

> UPD 2 Установил и запустил **PhpMyAdmin**, как предложено было в ответе [@diman.suvor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/329662/diman-suvor) — всё ок. Просмотрев в директориях тем (`/themes/*/css`) я нигде не обнаружил файла `theme.css`, как и в инструменте разработчика в броузере `chrome`.  К **PhpMyAdmin** установленной через офф. репозиторий выше указанный файл не подключается.

Comment: добрался сегодня до данного вопроса. 1) Установил через VirtualBox x64 Ubuntu 16.04. 2) Обновил до версии 18.04. 3) Установил LAMP (версия PHP 7.2). 4) Установил всё необходимое ПО, указанное в инструкции PMA удовлетворяющее минимальным требованиям. 5) Создал необходимый .conf-файл для Apache. Перезагрузил сервис. 6) Прописал в /etc/hosts. 7) `git clone ...` 8) `composer update` -> вылезло несколько ошибок (недоустановленные пакеты PHP, отсутствие прав на запись и т.д.). Пофиксил. 9) `yarn install`. 10) В Chrome последней версии всё открылось, стили подтянулись.

Comment: Поэтому посмотрите, что в логах. Возможно там есть интересная информация. Или тогда уже перейти в чат для общения.

Comment: @Kosmos Спасибо. Но я уже перешел на DBeave rhttps://dbeaver.io/

Comment: Как альтернатива :) Ещё есть хороший инструмент SQL Yog - но он платный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй переустановить по этой [инструкции](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-18-04) По-крайней мере, сначала на Ubuntu, а потом на Debian так его ставил, всё норм.

Comment: У меня уже настроена БД.  Я удалил apache2. Nginx не выводит. + выдаёт ошибку: `mysql said: ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user  debian-sys-maint@localhost to database`. Причём указываю `root`

Comment: Установил `apache2`. Переустановил `pma`. По инструкции не запускается.

Comment: @doox911, а из консоли подключается?
`mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Конечно) Я не могу открыть  `pma` в броузере

Comment: mysql said: ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user debian-sys-maint@localhost to database
А не root@localhost должен быть?

Comment: В том то и прикол) Я опустил настройку подключения. Я не могу увидеть стартовую страницу `pma`. Она ведь должна быть доступна по адресу: 'http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin'

Comment: Попробуй `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Comment: Не помогло. Он предлагает мне БД, затем выбрать apache2 и всё.

Comment: А localhost в браузере открывается?

Comment: Да, открывается)

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
Должна быть строка:
`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`
Есть?

Comment: И что вообще на этой странице показывается?

Comment: Плюсую ваш ответ. Но не принимаю, так как решение необходимо именно с такой установкой `PMA`

Comment: @doox911, в исходниках вижу папку /scss (и практически пустую папку /css). Пробовали её компилировать?

Comment: @Kosmos так там должны быть не css файлы, а файлы php